# How to find class table mapping in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

My hibernate-mapping.hbm.xml looks like this:

< ?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

< !DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

< hibernate-mapping>

< sql-query name="addAM">

```
< ![CDATA[INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_MEMBER (EXT_CUST_ID,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_DATE,ARCHIVAL_DATE)values(?,?,?,?)]]>
```

< /sql-query>

< sql-query name="saveServiceHistory">

< ![CDATA[INSERT INTO MEMBER_SERVICE_RECORD (MEMBER_ID, SERVICE_DATE,SERVICE_MILEAGE, SERVICE_DESC, MODIFIED_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]]>

< /sql-query>

...// many more such named queries

< /hibernate>

But there is nothing like < class name = "abc" table = "ABC"> in this hibernate file. Also, my classes don't have annotations. How are these getting mapped to specific classes then!

Comment: Btw, it would be helpful if you could specify which Hibernate version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't mention which Hibernate version you're on, those seems native named SQL queries.
In newer Hibernate release you should check out

```
EntityManager#createNamedQuery
```

While in legacy releases you should check out the Hibernate

```
Session#getNamedQuery
```

As per documentation, mapping an *entity* is not mandatory.
You can also query by receving an `Object[]`.

Comment: will check, thank you. there's another < project>-context.xml file where I am seeing < bean id="abc" class=" full.package.path.ABC " > tags and in the same .xml file lies my hibernate configurations details as well like <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    < prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
    < prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
    < prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
    < prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">15</prop>

Comment: @BharadwajJoshi those Beans are not related to your Hibernate mappings. Anyway, you can definitely update the named queries and add a specific entity mapping if you feel more confident that way. Just try it out.